# How can I create procedure in PostgreSQL which will delete rows from table

Tags: postgresql, procedure

I want to create a procedure in PostgreSQL database which will delete the data older than 3 month from table and should commit after every day of deleting and then continue deleting until reaching the 3 month interval.
I wrote sql but have trouble with procedure.

delete
from testdrop
where create_date<=current_date - interval '3 month';

Thanks in advance.

I created the procedure like below but I don't know how include here the committing after every day of deleting.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_drop()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    c RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR c IN ( delete
        from testdrop
     where create_date<=current_date - interval '3 month';
    )
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Postgres does not support scheduled tasks/trigger by its own. You can install 3rd party modules that will call the function OR use an external system to invoke it. I would create own module since DB connections and dependencies to other systems should not rise.

Comment: I don't want to automate this process. I just want when I run this procedure manually this procedure just delete rows from my table and commit after every 1 day data deleting.

Comment: So there should be a better issue description - anyway thats why i am writing comments no answers. What you can do/try is: Do it batch wise by amount or day by day and commit in the end OR sort by days. When ever "current date" changes you can commit using a if on handling list of data. In both cases SQL and commit command can be looped and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a list of dates you want to delete and execute each date in a single delete statement. You can use generate_series() to create the list of dates. Something like this should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_drop()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    _r RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR _r IN
        SELECT CAST(d AS DATE) d
        FROM GENERATE_SERIES(
                     (SELECT MIN(create_date) FROM testdrop) -- where to start
                 , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '3 months' -- where to end
                 , INTERVAL '1 day') gs(d)
        ORDER BY d
        LOOP
            DELETE
            FROM testdrop
            WHERE create_date >= _r.d
              AND create_date < (_r.d + INTERVAL '1 day'); -- delete single day
            RAISE NOTICE 'Date deleted: %', _r.d;
            COMMIT; -- commit just this single day
        END LOOP;
END ;
$$;
```

Comment: Hi Frank. System gave report that rows are deleted but actually it didn't delete the rows(That dates).

Comment: Impossible to see what's going on, we don't have access to your database. The column `create_date`, is that a date or a timestamp ? I presume it's a date, like the name says, but could be wrong. If it's a timestamp, you have to change the DELETE statement

Comment: My table **create_date** column data is like this "2023-12-26 00:00:13.683138". I think it is a TIMESTAMP

Comment: @KyoshPietro See the updated procedure, this should work fine. Next time also share the DDL of your table, to avoid issues like this

Comment: I will Frank. It works. Thank you very much for your help.